# swipe button issue in tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using 3 buttons on trailing swipe in a tableview, but when I swipe within the button section then two buttons are gone invisible only one button is visible and action are also trigged automatically.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        
        let viewButton = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            // View action
            print("View action")
            
        }
        viewButton.backgroundColor = ColorSet.appSkyLightColor
        viewButton.image = UIImage(named: "view")
    
        //Approve
    
        let approveButton = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            // approve action
            print("approve action")
            
        }
        approveButton.backgroundColor = ColorSet.appSkyLightColor
        approveButton.image = UIImage(named: "accept")
    
    
        //Reject
    
        let rejectButton = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            // Reject action
            print("Reject action")
            
        }
        rejectButton.backgroundColor = ColorSet.appSkyLightColor
        rejectButton.image = UIImage(named: "reject")
        
        let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [rejectButton, approveButton, viewButton])
        
        return swipeActions
   }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
swipeActions.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
```